# How do I print the path using Dijkstra's shortest path in c?

Tags: c, dijkstra

I was working on a program that prints the distance and the path. I got the distance working well, but the problem I am having comes when I try to print the path. I have tried a bunch of things that have resulted in segmentation faults or just printing MAX_INT. Right now it is just printing the nodes with the shortest weight backward, regardless if the node is in the path or not.

Here is the code and attached will be a graph, and please note that I am going to alter this to take in user input for source and destination, but for me just testing the code I just made the source 0 and the destination 4. Also attached is a photo of the graph. 
[GRAPH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15yMT.jpg)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

struct AdjListNode
{
    int dest;
    int weight;
    struct AdjListNode* next;
};

struct AdjList
{
    struct AdjListNode *head;  // pointer to head node of list
};

struct Graph
{
    int V;
    struct AdjList* array;
};

struct AdjListNode* newAdjListNode(int dest, int weight)
{
    struct AdjListNode* newNode =
            (struct AdjListNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct AdjListNode));
    newNode->dest = dest;
    newNode->weight = weight;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

struct Graph* createGraph(int V)
{
    struct Graph* graph = (struct Graph*) malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
    graph->V = V;

    // Create an array of adjacency lists.  Size of array will be V
    graph->array = (struct AdjList*) malloc(V * sizeof(struct AdjList));

     // Initialize each adjacency list as empty by making head as NULL
    for (int i = 0; i < V; ++i)
        graph->array[i].head = NULL;

    return graph;
}

void addEdge(struct Graph* graph, int src, int dest, int weight)
{
    // Add an edge from src to dest.  A new node is added to the adjacency
    // list of src.  The node is added at the begining
    struct AdjListNode* newNode = newAdjListNode(dest, weight);
    newNode->next = graph->array[src].head;
    graph->array[src].head = newNode;

    // Since graph is undirected, add an edge from dest to src also
    newNode = newAdjListNode(src, weight);
    newNode->next = graph->array[dest].head;
    graph->array[dest].head = newNode;
}

struct MinHeapNode
{
    int  v;
    int dist;
    struct MinHeapNode *parent;
};

struct MinHeap
{
    int size;      // Number of heap nodes present currently
    int capacity;  // Capacity of min heap
    int *pos;     // This is needed for decreaseKey()
    struct MinHeapNode **array;
};

struct MinHeapNode* newMinHeapNode(int v, int dist)
{
    struct MinHeapNode* minHeapNode =
           (struct MinHeapNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct MinHeapNode));
    minHeapNode->v = v;
    minHeapNode->dist = dist;
    return minHeapNode;
}

struct MinHeap* createMinHeap(int capacity)
{
    struct MinHeap* minHeap =
         (struct MinHeap*) malloc(sizeof(struct MinHeap));
    minHeap->pos = (int *)malloc(capacity * sizeof(int));
    minHeap->size = 0;
    minHeap->capacity = capacity;
    minHeap->array =
         (struct MinHeapNode**) malloc(capacity * sizeof(struct MinHeapNode*));
    return minHeap;
}

void swapMinHeapNode(struct MinHeapNode** a, struct MinHeapNode** b)
{
    struct MinHeapNode* t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}

void minHeapify(struct MinHeap* minHeap, int idx)
{
    int smallest, left, right;
    smallest = idx;
    left = 2 * idx + 1;
    right = 2 * idx + 2;

    if (left < minHeap->size &&
        minHeap->array[left]->dist < minHeap->array[smallest]->dist )
      smallest = left;

    if (right < minHeap->size &&
        minHeap->array[right]->dist < minHeap->array[smallest]->dist )
      smallest = right;

    if (smallest != idx)
    {
        MinHeapNode *smallestNode = minHeap->array[smallest];
        MinHeapNode *idxNode = minHeap->array[idx];

        minHeap->pos[smallestNode->v] = idx;
        minHeap->pos[idxNode->v] = smallest;

        swapMinHeapNode(&minHeap->array[smallest], &minHeap->array[idx]);

        minHeapify(minHeap, smallest);
    }
}

int isEmpty(struct MinHeap* minHeap)
{
    return minHeap->size == 0;
}

struct MinHeapNode* extractMin(struct MinHeap* minHeap)
{
    if (isEmpty(minHeap))
        return NULL;

    struct MinHeapNode* root = minHeap->array[0];

    struct MinHeapNode* lastNode = minHeap->array[minHeap->size - 1];
    minHeap->array[0] = lastNode;

    minHeap->pos[root->v] = minHeap->size-1;
    minHeap->pos[lastNode->v] = 0;

    --minHeap->size;
    minHeapify(minHeap, 0);

    return root;
}

void decreaseKey(struct MinHeap* minHeap, int v, int dist)
{
    int i = minHeap->pos[v];

    minHeap->array[i]->dist = dist;

    while (i && minHeap->array[i]->dist < minHeap->array[(i - 1) / 2]->dist)
    {
        minHeap->pos[minHeap->array[i]->v] = (i-1)/2;
        minHeap->pos[minHeap->array[(i-1)/2]->v] = i;
        swapMinHeapNode(&minHeap->array[i],  &minHeap->array[(i - 1) / 2]);

        i = (i - 1) / 2;
    }
}

bool isInMinHeap(struct MinHeap *minHeap, int v)
{
   if (minHeap->pos[v] < minHeap->size)
     return true;
   return false;
}

void printLength(int dist[], int n,int des)
{

    printf("LENGTH: %d",dist[des]);

}

void printPath (struct MinHeapNode *last, int source,int des)
{
    printf ("\nPATH\n");
    while (last != NULL)
    {
        printf ("%d ,  ", last->v);

        last = last->parent;
    }


}

void dijkstra(struct Graph* graph, int src, int des)
{
    int V = graph->V;// Get the number of vertices in graph
    int dist[V];      // dist values used to pick minimum weight edge in cut

    // minHeap represents set E
    struct MinHeap* minHeap = createMinHeap(V);

    // Initialize min heap with all vertices. dist value of all vertices
    for (int v = 0; v < V; ++v)
    {
        //parent[0]= -1;
        dist[v] = INT_MAX;
        minHeap->array[v] = newMinHeapNode(v, dist[v]);
        minHeap->pos[v] = v;
    }

    // Make dist value of src vertex as 0 so that it is extracted first
    minHeap->array[src] = newMinHeapNode(src, dist[src]);
    minHeap->pos[src] = src;
    dist[src] = 0;
    decreaseKey(minHeap, src, dist[src]);

    // Initially size of min heap is equal to V
    minHeap->size = V;

    struct MinHeapNode *prev = NULL;
    // In the followin loop, min heap contains all nodes
    // whose shortest distance is not yet finalized.
    while (!isEmpty(minHeap))
    {
        // Extract the vertex with minimum distance value
        struct MinHeapNode* minHeapNode = extractMin(minHeap);
        minHeapNode->parent = prev;
        prev = minHeapNode;

        int u = minHeapNode->v; // Store the extracted vertex number

        // Traverse through all adjacent vertices of u (the extracted
        // vertex) and update their distance values
        struct AdjListNode* pCrawl = graph->array[u].head;
        while (pCrawl != NULL)
        {
            int v = pCrawl->dest;

            // If shortest distance to v is not finalized yet, and distance to v
            // through u is less than its previously calculated distance
            if (isInMinHeap(minHeap, v) && dist[u] != INT_MAX &&
                pCrawl->weight + dist[u] < dist[v])
            {

                dist[v] = dist[u] + pCrawl->weight;


                // update distance value in min heap also
                decreaseKey(minHeap, v, dist[v]);


            }
            pCrawl = pCrawl->next;
        }
    }

    // print the calculated shortest distances
    printLength(dist, src,des);
    printPath(prev,src,des);


}
int main() 
{ 
    // create the graph given in above fugure 
    int V = 9; 
    struct Graph* graph = createGraph(V); 
    addEdge(graph, 0, 1, 4); 
    addEdge(graph, 0, 7, 8); 
    addEdge(graph, 1, 2, 8); 
    addEdge(graph, 1, 7, 11); 
    addEdge(graph, 2, 3, 7); 
    addEdge(graph, 2, 8, 2); 
    addEdge(graph, 2, 5, 4); 
    addEdge(graph, 3, 4, 9); 
    addEdge(graph, 3, 5, 14); 
    addEdge(graph, 4, 5, 10); 
    addEdge(graph, 5, 6, 2); 
    addEdge(graph, 6, 7, 1); 
    addEdge(graph, 6, 8, 6); 
    addEdge(graph, 7, 8, 7); 

    dijkstra(graph, 0,4); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Sure about C++? Looks more like C (at least to me).

Comment: There is no such thing as "c/c++". Please read the descriptions of the tags that you applied. Also, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I just fixed it, sorry about that. This is in C but I will later use headers and other things in c++ with this code. but for now  answer in c.

Comment: @RobJames, You have done bad editing (or erasing) your question, as it is not going to be profitable to anyone after this.  You'd better to leave it as it was, instead of erasing it's contents, so it can be of help to anybody later. Once the problem is solved, probably it's of no more interest to you, but people search here for answers before asking their questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Dijkstra's algorithm, you are adding new nodes (the shortest leg) to the *already visited node set* until you include the destination in it.  Let's assume you include a field `prev` (a pointer to a node) into the `struct AdjListNode`, as long as you include the nodes in the set of already reachable nodes, you make that pointer to point to the node it was attached from, when you added the node to the reachable nodes set.  As long as the node it is attached to has already been added, it will have its `prev` node pointing to the node it was attached to... and so on.  The first node (the departure node) just points nowhere (it is `NULL`, as it has never been marked ---it was already in the set when you begun), so you have the inverse path to the origin node, by following the pointers `prev` from each visited node to the origin. You can write a subroutine like this:

```
void print_path(struct AdjListNode *nod, FILE *out)
{
    /* recurse until the origin */
    if (nod->prev) {
        print_path(nod->prev, out);
        fprintf(out, "->"); /* separator */
    }
    fprintf(out, "d=%5(w=%d)", 
         nod->dest, nod->weight);
}
```

that pointer is very useful, as for each visited node it stores the route to the origin over the shortest path, not just for the node you are interested in.

## Note

I've not checked your implementation, as you said that your problem was only in finding the actual route to the destination, so I will not include your code patched.  I just leave that to you, as an exercise.  I try only to give you a *hint*, not to solve your homework.  My apologies for that.

## 2nd Note

I've written a complete implementation of the algorithm.  This will be probably well translated to C++, as you noted in your comments, you should need it.  It is composed of three files, `main.c` (main program), `dijkstra.h` (header with structure definitions) and `dijkstra.c` (implementation)  It is available [here](https://github.com/mojadita/dijkstra).

Comment: I figured it out a long time ago haha. I should have even asked this my problem was a dumb error.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, I am pretty sure the main issue is that you do not actually implement Dijkstra's algorithm.

In particular, you don't need to work through all nodes (which is what you are currently doing). Instead, starting from the start, you follow the shortest possible path until you reach the destination.

In the beginning, you put exactly one node into your minHeap: the start node with distance 0.

Your loop should take the top element from the heap, check if it is the destination. If yes, break. Otherwise put all unvisited neighbors with their respective distance (distance of the current node + edge weight) in to the min heap.

During this traversal, it makes sense to store the node you came from for each visited node. This allows you to traverse the path back, once you reach the destination.

That being said: I also have doubts about your min heap. I am not sure what you are doing there, but once the user of the min heap is starting to access elements by index, the design is most definitely broken.

Comment: Its not printing the path. It is just printing all the nodes even if they are in the path or not.

Comment: Replaced answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code to print the path backwards:

```
v = end_node
while v != start_node
     print(v)
     v = adjacent node for which a sum: distance + edge_weight(v,adjacent) is minimum
print (v) // print start node
```

It's based on the observation that edge for which `dist + edge_weight` is minimum is on the path (when looking backwards).

Comment: I want to print the path so that it is ai correct order. I understand the pseudocode I just need to know how to actually implement it with this code.

Comment: If you want correct order first store nodes on the list and print it backwards.

Comment: Is it your code? I deducted you will be able to write it on your own I you were able to write this code. Sorry, I won't write all the code for you :(

Comment: The problem I was having was not explained well by me. What was happening was it was printing all the nodes not just a few. I don’t need you to actually write the code I just wanted to know why it wasn’t printing paths properly